# If Enum Has specific flag, check to see if it has any others

Tags: c#, enums

I have a rather large Flag enum called `AmendmentType`. I need to check to see that if it has specific Enums and any others.

For Example:

```
var foo = AmendmentType.Item1;

if (foo.HasFlag(AmendmentType.Item1) && (ANYTHING ELSE))
{
//DO NOT ALLOW
}
else if (foo.HasFlag(AmendmentType.Item2) && foo.HasFlag(AmendmentType.Item6))
{
//DO NOT ALLOW
}
else
{
//ALLOW
}
```

How would this be possible? There are about 20 different items in the Flag Enum and it seems like there should be an easier way than checking all possible combinations.

Comment: why not just `if(foo.HasFlag(1) || foo.HasFlag(2).. )` etc?

Comment: So are you *just* asking about the "anything else" part?

Comment: Yes, what would would I check to get "Anything else"?

Comment: Right - you could make that a *lot* clearer in the post... especially if only the first line of your code is really relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only interested in the part you've labeled as "anything else", you can use:

```
if (foo.HasFlag(AmendmentTypeEnum.Item1) && (foo & ~AmendmentTypeEnum.Item1) != 0)
```

Or just check that it isn't exactly equal to `Item1`:

```
if (foo.HasFlag(AmendmentTypeEnum.Item1) && foo != AmendmentTypeEnum.Item1)
```

Note that checking for the presence of *all* of multiple flags only needs a single `HasFlag` call too:

```
else if (foo.HasFlag(AmendmentTypeEnum.Item2 | AmendmentTypeEnum.Item6))
```

(I'd also suggest removing the `Enum` suffix - it'll be a lot easier to read the code without it :)

Comment: In the first case, wouldn't `if (foo.HasFlag(AmendmentTypeEnum.Item) && foo == AmendmentTypeEnum.Item1)` work?

Comment: @JimMischel: Did you mean `!=`? If so, I agree... otherwise, no - it would do the opposite of what's required.

Comment: Yep, this worked. Can't believe I didn't think to see if foo was just equal to the specific item!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set up flags that signify the combinations you're interested in.

```
var flagComboA = AmendmentTypeEnum.Item1;
var flagComboB = AmendmentTypeEnum.Item2 | AmendmentTypeEnum.Item6;

if(foo == flagComboA || foo == flagComboB) 
{
     //DO NOT ALLOW
}
```